# MapReduce example in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, count, mapreduce, cpu-word

I have this problem in Scala for a Homework.
The idea I have had but have not been able to successfully implement is

Iterate through each word, if the word is basketball, take the next word and add it to a map. Reduce by key, and sort from highest to lowest.

Unfortunately I do not know how to take the next next word in a list of words.
For example, i would like to do something like this:

```
val lines = spark.textFile("basketball_words_only.txt") // process lines in file

// split into individual words
val words = lines.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))

var listBuff = new ListBuffer[String]() // a list Buffer to hold each following word

val it = Iterator(words)  

while (it.hasNext) {
  listBuff += it.next().next() // <-- this is what I would like to do    
}

val follows = listBuff.map(word => (word, 1))
val count = follows.reduceByKey((x, y) => x + y) // another issue as I cannot reduceByKey with a listBuffer

val sort = count.sortBy(_._2,false,1)

val result2 = sort.collect()

for (i <- 0 to result2.length - 1) {
 printf("%s follows %d times\n", result1(2)._1, result2(i)._2);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the max count for the first word in all distinct word pairs in a few steps:

1. Strip punctuations, split content into words which get lowercased
2. Use `sliding(2)` to create array of word pairs
3. Use `reduceByKey` to count occurrences of distinct word pairs
4. Use `reduceByKey` again to capture word pairs with max count for the first word

Sample code as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions._

val wordPairCountRDD = sc.textFile("/path/to/textfile").
  flatMap( _.split("""[\s,.;:!?]+""") ).
  map( _.toLowerCase ).
  sliding(2).
  map{ case Array(w1, w2) => ((w1, w2), 1) }.
  reduceByKey( _ + _ )

val wordPairMaxRDD = wordPairCountRDD.
  map{ case ((w1, w2), c) => (w1, (w2, c)) }.
  reduceByKey( (acc, x) =>
    if (x._2 > acc._2) (x._1, x._2) else acc
  ).
  map{ case (w1, (w2, c)) => ((w1, w2), c) }
```

[UPDATE]

If you only need the word pair counts to be sorted (in descending order) per your revised requirement, you can skip step 4 and use `sortBy` on `wordPairCountRDD`:

```
wordPairCountRDD.
  sortBy( z => (z._2, z._1._1, z._1._2), ascending = false )
```

Comment: @Eee, please see my updated answer to your question with revised requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This is from https://spark.apache.org/examples.html:

```
val counts = textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))   
                     .map(word => (word, 1))
                     .reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

As you can see it counts the occurrence of individual words because the key-value pairs are of the form (word, 1). Which part do you need to change to count combinations of words?

This might help you: http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2009/11/iteratorsliding.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, my text uses "b" instead of "basketball" and "a", "c" for other words.

```
scala> val r = scala.util.Random 
scala> val s = (1 to 20).map (i => List("a", "b", "c")(r.nextInt (3))).mkString (" ")
s: String = c a c b a b a a b c a b b c c a b b c b
```

The result is gained by split, sliding, filter, map, groupBy, map and sortBy:

```
scala> val counts = s.split (" ").sliding (2).filter (_(0) == "b").map (_(1)).toList.groupBy (_(0)).map { case (c: Char, l: List[String]) => (c, l.size)}.toList.sortBy (-_._2) 
counts: List[(Char, Int)] = List((c,3), (b,2), (a,2))
```

In small steps, sliding:

```
scala> val counts = s.split (" ").sliding (2).toList
counts: List[Array[String]] = List(Array(c, a), Array(a, c), Array(c, b), Array(b, a), Array(a, b), Array(b, a), Array(a, a), Array(a, b), Array(b, c), Array(c, a), Array(a, b), Array(b, b), Array(b, c), Array(c, c), Array(c, a), Array(a, b), Array(b, b), Array(b, c), Array(c, b))
```

filter:

```
scala> val counts = s.split (" ").sliding (2).filter (_(0) == "b").toList
counts: List[Array[String]] = List(Array(b, a), Array(b, a), Array(b, c), Array(b, b), Array(b, c), Array(b, b), Array(b, c))
```

map (_(1)) (Array access element 2)

```
scala> val counts = s.split (" ").sliding (2).filter (_(0) == "b").map (_(1)).toList
counts: List[String] = List(a, a, c, b, c, b, c)
```

groupBy (_(0))

```
scala> val counts = s.split (" ").sliding (2).filter (_(0) == "b").map (_(1)).toList.groupBy (_(0))
counts: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,List[String]] = Map(b -> List(b, b), a -> List(a, a), c -> List(c, c, c))
```

to size of List:

```
scala> val counts = s.split (" ").sliding (2).filter (_(0) == "b").map (_(1)).toList.groupBy (_(0)).map { case (c: Char, l: List[String]) => (c, l.size)}
counts: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Int] = Map(b -> 2, a -> 2, c -> 3)
```

Finally sort descending:

```
scala> val counts = s.split (" ").sliding (2).filter (_(0) == "b").map (_(1)).toList.groupBy (_(0)).map { case (c: Char, l: List[String]) => (c, l.size)}.toList.sortBy (-_._2) 
counts: List[(Char, Int)] = List((c,3), (b,2), (a,2))
```